# Raw socket bind() in python 3.4.3 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, raw-sockets

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following Python code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.getprotobyname('icmp'))
s.bind((interface_ip_address, 0))
```

I'm trying to send an ICMP packet through a user selected interface, but I keep getting SocketError when using the bind() function. I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Update:

When user selects loopback interface (interface_ip_address = 127.0.0.1) than

```
s.bind((interface_ip_address, 0))
```

works like a charm! But why does it raise SoccektError when user selects any of the reamining interfaces?

Comment: run the script as administrator

Comment: I am running it as an Adminstrator, and when I remove the bind command it all works just fine. The problem is when I try to bind the socket to the specific interface.